# Difference between rendering an SFC or calling a function that returns an element

Tags: reactjs

Consider the following code:

```js
function Foo({a}) {
    return (<h1>{a}</h1>);
}

function bar(a) {
    return (<h1>{a}</h1>);
}

render(<Foo a="Hey" />, document.body);
render(bar("Hey"), document.body);
```

Is there any observable difference between rendering an SFC as an element or calling a function that returns an element? Why would I want/not want `Foo` to be part of the element tree given it's stateless and effectless? Are there any performance implications? Maybe better debuggability using React DevTools?

Answer (score 0):

Calling SFCs directly is a hack that should be used only where it's suitable. In order to do that, developer should be certain that a component is functional and be aware of how it works. Functional components cannot be called directly if they use [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html).

In this specific case there is no practical difference between `Foo` and `bar`.

Both `Foo` and `bar` provide ways to return React element. `Foo` is conventional (functional component) that can be used either as a component or be called as a function. `bar` is not conventional, just a function that cannot be used as a component.

Comment: Yep, I wasn't trying to endorse calling SFC as functions, more about the difference between an SFC and just a function that returns elements but which in itself is not an SFC. I'll try to clarify the question.

Comment: There's no practical difference *in this case*, except that `bar` is not conventional and may outrage your coworkers. I don't see any difference debuggability *in this case*, obviously, `Foo` will be shown in React dev tools as root component and `bar` will not. If you're asking not about this case but about any possible case then there will be differences. `bar` doesn't have all benefits of SFC while providing no own benefits. I'd say this is enough to never use `bar`.